# Optimizar función javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código:

```
<html>Código 128: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]"id="nro_cod1" value="128" onclick="habil_fecha()"/> <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod1" disabled="true" value="<?php echo "$fec_cod"; ?>"><br><br>
Código 129: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod2" value="129" onclick="habil_fecha()"/> <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod2" disabled="true" value="<?php echo "$fec_cod"; ?>"><br><br>
Código 349: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod3" value="349" onclick="habil_fecha()"/> <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod3" disabled="true" value="<?php echo "$fec_cod"; ?>"><br><br>
Código 384: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod4" value="384" onclick="habil_fecha()"/> <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod4" disabled="true" value="<?php echo "$fec_cod"; ?>"><br><br></html>
```

y la funcion

```
<script>
 function habil_fecha(){
if(document.formulario.nro_cod1.checked == true){
  document.formulario.fec_cod1.disabled = false;
  }
else{
  document.formulario.fec_cod1.disabled = true;
  }
if(document.formulario.nro_cod2.checked == true){
  document.formulario.fec_cod2.disabled = false;
  }
else{
  document.formulario.fec_cod2.disabled = true;
  }
}
if(document.formulario.nro_cod3.checked == true){
  document.formulario.fec_cod3.disabled = false;
    }
else{
  document.formulario.fec_cod3.disabled = true;
    }
}
if(document.formulario.nro_cod4.checked == true){
  document.formulario.fec_cod4.disabled = false;
    }
else{
  document.formulario.fec_cod4.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Cada "Código xxx" junto a su fecha correspondiente van a ser insertado en una tabla con campos `nro_cod` y `fec_cod`, respectivamente en una base de datos MySQL, mediante código php. La función JavaScript la utilizo para que cuando se tilda el `checkbox` se habilite el campo fecha que le corresponde. La consulta es si se puede optimizar la función `habil_fec()` trabajando con los array de cada "name" de los input `nro_cod[]` y `fec_cod[]`. Como está cumple con lo que necesito y los tiempos que manejo realmente no me permiten detenerme más en el tema. Sólo es que quisiera saber como optimizarla. Desde ya agradecido.

Comment: Bueno rectifico: la funcion '<script>
function habil_fecha(){
  if(document.formulario.nro_cod1.checked == true){
      document.formulario.fec_cod1.disabled = false;
      }
  else{
      document.formulario.fec_cod1.disabled = true;
      }} </script>' habilita el campo fec_cod1 pero para que los campos similares tengan los mismos resultados debo hacer una funcion habil_fec para cada par.

Comment: Podes usar jQuery o sólo JavaScript?

Comment: Debo añadir soy novato... poco sé de jQuery @JuanSalvadorPortugal

Comment: Pero incluis la librería en tu proyecto?

Comment: Ahora en 5 minutitos te armo una respuesta con jQuery por si te sirve :D

Comment: No he usado jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando jQuery puede hacerse practicamente en una línea, por ejemplo

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"').on('change',function(){  
$(this).next('input[type="date"]').prop('disabled',!$(this).prop('checked'));  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="codigo">Código 128: 
<input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod1" value="128"  /> 
<input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod1" disabled="true" value="23" /> 

<p class="codigo">Código 129: 
<input class=""
  type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod2" value="129" /> <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod2" disabled="true" value="23"></p>
  
<p class="codigo">Código 349: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]"
  id="nro_cod3" value="349" />
  <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod3" disabled="true" value="23"/></p>

<p class="codigo">Código 384: 
  <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod4" value="384"
  /> 
  <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod4" disabled="true" value="23"></p>
```

Comment: Como detalle, te faltaría cerrar el input type checkbox

Comment: @Jakala No se a que `checkbox` te referís, yo los veo todos cerrados, si se me esta pasando, porfavor, edita mi respuesta cerrándolo!

Comment: En el javascript, la primera línea, el input type=checkbox, no tiene cerrado el corchete. No me deja editar, debo cambiar 6 o más caracteres....te lo dejo a ti ok?

Answer (score 2):

He cambiado un poco el HTML porque para la demostración el PHP es un estorbo. A continuación viene mi código. Espero que lo encuentres útil.

```js
let codigoRy = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".codigo"));

codigoRy.map((p) =>{
  p.checkbox = p.querySelector("[type='checkbox']");
  p.date = p.querySelector("[type='date']");
  p.checkbox.addEventListener("change",()=>{
    if(p.checkbox.checked){p.date.disabled = false;}else{p.date.disabled = true;}
  })
})
```

```html
<p class="codigo">Código 128: 
<input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod1" value="128"  /> 
<input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod1" disabled="true" value="23" /> 
                                                                               <p class="codigo">Código 129: 
<input class=""
  type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod2" value="129" /> <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod2" disabled="true" value="23"></p>
  
<p class="codigo">Código 349: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]"
  id="nro_cod3" value="349" />
  <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod3" disabled="true" value="23"/></p>

<p class="codigo">Código 384: 
  <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod4" value="384"
  /> 
  <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod4" disabled="true" value="23"></p>
```

Comment: +1 por el uso de lambda

Comment: pero debería usar `forEach` en lugar de `map`

Comment: Inclui en la cabecera de mi formulario '<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' que obviamente esta guardado en la misma carpeta que el formulario y el código de jQuery de tu respuesta lo incluí entre dos etiquetas '<script>'. Pero no funciona. Qué me falta? O qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Gracias DieWalever por tu comentario. Mi código no utiliza JQuery. Es vanilla. Si haces click en el botón que dice "ejecutar" verás que sí funciona. A lo mejor no has visto que el HTML esta cambiado. He añadido unos `<p class="codigo">`

Answer (score 0):

Otra solucion, en este caso javascript sin lamdas:

```
<script>
 function habil_fecha(field){
      aux =  field.attr('id').split("_");
      fec = "fec_"+ aux[1];
      document.getElementById(fec).disabled = ! field.checked;
 }</script>
```

Lo que hacemos es recibir el elemento actual (se envia en el html como this). Dividimos el id del atributo ID, para cojer el segundo termino, esto es, guarda `nro` en aux[0] y `cod1` en aux[1]. Eso nos permite crear el fec_cod correspondiente. Por ultimo lo buscamos y le asignamos el valor contrario al de checkeado (si checked es true, entonces disable debe ser false).

y en el html pasamos el elemento actual a la funcion:

```
Código 128: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]"id="nro_cod1" value="128" onclick="habil_fecha(this)"/> 
            <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod1" disabled="true" value="<?php echo "$fec_cod"; ?>"><br><br>
Código 129: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod2" value="129" onclick="habil_fecha(this)"/> 
            <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod2" disabled="true" value="<?php echo "$fec_cod"; ?>"><br><br>
Código 349: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod3" value="349" onclick="habil_fecha(this)"/>  
            <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod3" disabled="true" value="<?php echo "$fec_cod"; ?>"><br><br>
Código 384: <input class="" type="checkbox" name="nro_cod[]" id="nro_cod4" value="384" onclick="habil_fecha(this)"/> 
            <input type="date" name="fec_cod[]" id="fec_cod4" disabled="true" value="<?php echo "$fec_cod"; ?>"><br><br>
```